# VBA group by process using Public Types

Tags: arrays, vba, group-by, countif

I want to create a counter in a routine that will count how many times a specific entry has appeared so far.

The routine that i have created so far populates data in a spreadsheet through a For..Next Loop. For each of these rows i have an extra column that will represent the counter and count how many times a characteristic of the entry row has appeared so far in the previous rows. For that, I am using the application.worksheetfunction.CountIf function but the reference range has to be dynamic.

For example, I have the following table
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7wBY.png)

the overall idea is to group by month and expense type and have the sum amount. The role of the counter is to identify these rows that can be grouped together and loop through their values and sum them. The table has approximately 10,000 rows and 53 columns. For this process, i have created the following public type:

```
>public type OP
>>Month as string
>>expense_type as string
>>amount as double
>end type

Sub NewOuput()
with sheet1

>for i=1 lastrow 'output is the existing table that i get the data and i want to manipulate and then populate them into another table of the same format
>>op.month=output(i,1)
>>op.expense_type=output(i,2)
>>op.amount=output(i,3)
'----------------------------
>> .cells(i,1)=op.month 'this is the population of hte data in the new table
>> .cells(i,2)=op.expense_type
>> .cells(i,3)=op.amount
next i
end with
end sub
```

Through functions, i try to identify the rows that need to sum-up and then call the respective functions in the output part of the loop.

Countif excel function cannot be appied with arrays, so this is now out of hte question. I have read many posts on various ways of grouping including data connections, collections and other customised approaches. Collections appeared to be the best ones but i miss some of hte background there.
Does this make any sense? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: add more example of starting data and their processing results

Comment: @user3598756 thanks for your reply. I have uploaded the core code and an example of what i want to process. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually grasp your exact needs, but since the table example image I'd go like follows:

```
Sub NewOuput()

    With sheet1

        'fill in the voids of 1st column
        With .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row) '<--| change "A" and "B" to your actual 1st and 2nd columns index
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        'more code to exploit a "full" database structure


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks for the feedback! I see your point. I decided to use a recorded macro to automate a manual step and create the counter. It was taking me too long to go through this point - which was an intermediate step - to reach the final point which was to "group by". I finally managed to group and sum using types and arrays. Many thanks for your time!it is very helpfull!